Quering the instalation prefix of a c library with pkg-config
I am writing Makefile that installs a c shared library to the system, including the .pc file for pkg-config. I would like to add an uninstall target, but the location of it will depend on the PREFIX given by the user (by writing PREFIX=$(DEST) make install). Is there a simple way to get the actual prefix used on installation (other than reading the generated .pc file, for which I would also have to have the prefix) using pkg-config or any other program?
